# Do i have to include xml namespaces in the svcutil.exe command?

Tags: .net, wcf, wsdl, svcutil.exe

I need to create a proxy class so i can communicate with a Java web service (which i have no control over).

The web service is supposed to be implemeting the [catalog (CSW) OGC standard](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/cat). However There are NO includes or imports in the wsdl just namespace referencing at the top of the wsdl like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsd:definitions xmlns:wsd="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl" xmlns:csw="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap" xmlns:tns="http://www.mda.ca/hma/wsdl1.1" xmlns:wrs="http://www.opengis.net/cat/wrs/1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ...
```

So my TWO part question is:

1. Are these xmlns tags enough for me to create a proxy from? ( i would think not because i think they are just "hints" and not even the correct or valid location of any xsd files )
2. If so, should i be including them in my svcutil command like such:

> svcutil
>   http://wsdllocation.com/thewsdl.wsdl
>   http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2
>   ...

My problem is that i can't create a proxy class from this wsdl. I've tried adding "everyone" to my "c:/windows/temp/" directory with modify rights. I've tried calling the wsdl with svcutil directly. I've tried donwloading the wsdl along with the entire OGC schema files and including them all withing my svcutil command but still get the following error:

> ```
> Generating files...
> Warning: No code was generated.
> If you were trying to generate a client, this could be because the
> ```
>
> metadata documents did not contain any
>   valid co
>       ces
>       or because all contracts/services were discovered to exist in /reference
>   assemblies. Verify that you passed all
>   th
>       ents to the tool.
>
> ```
> Warning: If you would like to generate data contracts from schemas
> ```
>
> make sure to use the /dataContractOnly
>   option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you will need the actual schemas, and they will actually need to be referenced from the `<types>` section of the WSDL.

Can you post the URL of the WSDL? I'd like to see if it's valid.

Comment: please email me at ckrefft [at] rsmas.miami.edu. I will send you the downloaded wsdl in a zip. The thing is the wsdl is only available via certain IPs (firewalled). I appreciate it.

Comment: @John: I promise not to email you directly any other time other than to send you the wsdl file. (unless you ask me to). You have my word i will not bother you with more questions. They will all go through this site if anything.

Comment: @John: Well i have to give you the answer as i believe you've answered it. But i'd still appreciate you taking a look at the wsdl to see if it's a valid one.

Comment: @cap: I haven't received the WSDL yet.

Comment: @capdragon: is this the entire WSDL? There's no `<wsdl:types>` section, except for the one that's commented out. All the owners need to do is open the file in XMLSpy to see that it's invalid.

Comment: +2 for taking a look at the wsdl. Yes, this is the entire WSDL. If i add the <wsdl:types> to schema files i've downloaded from the standards authority that they are implemeting (OGC), I guess i should be on track? I'll give that a shot. Thanks for your help.